# Capturar os últimos caracteres em PHP de um arquivo XML

Tags: php

Eu tenho um arquivo sitemap do meu site.

```
...
<loc>https://www.site.com.br/aluno/jose/11111111111111/</loc>
<loc>https://www.site.com.br/aluno/jose/22222222222222/</loc>
<loc>https://www.site.com.br/aluno/jose/33333333333333/</loc>
...
```

Preciso capturar os últimos 14 dígitos de todas as urls.

Eu comecei da seguinte forma e travei:

```
<?php

function esquerda($str, $length) {
return substr($str, 0, $length);
}

$url = file_get_contents('https://site.com.br/sitemap.xml');

while (strpos($url,'/aluno/') > 0) {
    $url = substr($url,strpos($url,'/aluno/')+14);
    $numero = esquerda($url, 14);
    echo $numero;
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Mas não estou conseguindo ajeitar. Alguém consegue uma solução?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem que pegar o tamanho da `string` e diminuir pelo `$length`:

```
function esquerda($str, $length) 
{
    return substr($str, (strlen($str) - $length), $length);
}
```

---

[Exemplo ONLINE Ideone](https://ideone.com/MJJYqv)

```
<?php

    function esquerda($str, $length) 
    {
        return substr($str, (strlen($str) - $length), $length);
    }

    $n = '1400001';

    echo esquerda($n, 5); // resposta: 00001
```

Isso seria a idéia em cima do seu `xml` falta saber as chaves anteriores, mas, vou gerar um exemplo:

```
function esquerda($str, $length) 
{
    $length++;
    return substr($str, (strlen($str) - $length), $length - 1);
}

$xml = '<a>
    <loc>https://www.site.com.br/aluno/jose/11111111111111/</loc>
    <loc>https://www.site.com.br/aluno/jose/22222222222222/</loc>
    <loc>https://www.site.com.br/aluno/jose/33333333333333/</loc>
    </a>';

$simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($simpleXml->loc as $loc) 
{
    echo esquerda($loc, 14);
    echo '<br />';
}
```

se for um arquivo ou endereço pode fazer `simpleXML_load_file($url);` que também funciona.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [substr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php)
- [strlen](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strlen.php)

Comment: Não consegui. Como ficaria no código? Lembrando que eu preciso pegar todas os últimos números de todas as urls do sitemap.  Alterei a função e o retorno é: url>

Comment: @Marcelo tem como você colocar o `Xml` na sua pergunta, o que você realmente está usando?

Comment: Funcionou como você fez! Obrigado! Eu só tenho um problema: é possível colocar a url do sitemap ao invés do conteúdo? em $xml =

Comment: sim claro é só fazer assim @Marcelo coloque um comentário para utilizar `simpleXML_load_file($url)`

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você tem que ler o formato do XML, então pode usar `DOMDocument` ou `SimpleXML`, pro seu caso, que parece simples o segundo resolve:

Por exemplo:

```
<?php

$xmlstring = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>https://www.site.com.br/aluno/jose/11111111111111/</loc>
   </url>
   <url>
      <loc>https://www.site.com.br/aluno/jose/22222222222222/</loc>
   </url>
   <url>
      <loc>https://www.site.com.br/aluno/jose/33333333333333/</loc>
   </url>
</urlset>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);

foreach ($xml as $tag) {
    var_dump($tag->loc);
}
```

> Fiz o exemplo supondo que seja um sitemap

Agora se o XML for algo como:

```
<foo>
<loc>https://www.site.com.br/aluno/jose/11111111111111/</loc>
<loc>https://www.site.com.br/aluno/jose/22222222222222/</loc>
<loc>https://www.site.com.br/aluno/jose/33333333333333/</loc>
</foo>
```

Ai bastaria:

```
<?php

$xmlstring = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
<loc>https://www.site.com.br/aluno/jose/11111111111111/</loc>
<loc>https://www.site.com.br/aluno/jose/22222222222222/</loc>
<loc>https://www.site.com.br/aluno/jose/33333333333333/</loc>
</foo>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);

foreach ($xml as $tagFoo) {
    var_dump($tagFoo);
}
```

Se vier de uma URL pode usar `$xml = simpleXML_load_file('http://site/sitemap.xml');` ao invés de `$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);`

Seja qual o formato que for, basta ajustar para ler, agora vamos ao ponto de pegar a ultima parte da string.

Poderia fazer uma função como uma destas duas:

- Com `substr`

  ```
  function final_str($str, $delimitador = '/') {
      $str = trim($str, $delimitador); //Remove o delimitador do final

      $posicao = strrpos($str, $delimitador) + 1; //Pega a posição do ultimo delimitador (no seu caso /)

      return substr($str, $posicao); // Remove tudo antes do delimitador incluindo o delimitador
  }
  ```
- Com `explode`

  ```
  function final_str($str, $delimitador = '/') {
      $str = trim($str, $delimitador); //Remove o delimitador do final

      $partes = explode($delimitador, $str); //Separa a string em partes

      return $partes[count($partes) - 1]; //Pega a parte final da string
  }
  ```

E usaria assim:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);

foreach ($xml as $tag) {
    var_dump( final_str($tag->loc) );
}
```

Ou assim se vier de um URL:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('http://site.com/sitemap.xml');

foreach ($xml as $tag) {
    var_dump( final_str($tag->loc) );
}
```